# Rotating the MoviePlayer automatically created by YouTube link

Tags: xamarin.ios, youtube, rotation

I'm playing YouTube videos in my app - the app is Portrait only except that I'd like to have the videos play Landscape. I'm using the much publicized WebView method:

```
        public YouTubeViewer(string url, RectangleF frame)
        {
            string youTubeVideoHTML = @"<object width=""{1}"" height=""{2}""><param name=""movie""
            value=""{0}""></param><embed
            src=""{0}"" type=""application/x-shockwave-flash"" 
            width=""{1}"" height=""{2}""</embed></object>"; 

            string html = string.Format(youTubeVideoHTML, url, frame.Size.Width, frame.Size.Height);
            this.LoadHtmlString(html, null);
            this.Frame = frame;
    }
```

This works great except that the MoviePlayer is in Portrait orientation only. I've tried calling the WebView from within a new ViewController that supports ALL orientations, but it has no effect. I've tried rotating the WebView, but that does not affect the MoviePlayer that is magically called by the iOS.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

The app info.plist was set to only allow Portrait orientation. Changed that and the YouTube controller correctly rotates the MoviePlayer!